# Binary counterpart to decade

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, programming

In logarithms, a decade is a range of values from N up to 1o×N.

What term should be used to describe a range from N to 2×N, when using binary numbers?

A musical octave covers such a range of audible frequencies, but that term is probably too foreign.

Googling "binade" turns up a Wikipedia page, but also evidence that it's not a real word, but rather a neologism that's happened to get coined a few times.

I feel like I'm forgetting something from engineering school.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Octave*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_%28electronics%29) is apparently the proper word in electronics as well as music:

> In electronics, an octave is a doubling or halving of a frequency. The term is derived from the Western musical scale (an octave is a doubling in frequency) and is therefore common in audio electronics. (The prefix octa-, denoting eight, refers to the eight notes of a diatonic scale.) Along with the decade, it is a unit used to describe frequency bands or frequency ratios.

A similar note is posted in the opening paragraph of the corresponding entry on [*decade*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_%28log_scale%29):

> One decade is a factor of 10 difference between two numbers (an order of magnitude difference) measured on a logarithmic scale. Along with the octave, it is a unit used to describe frequency bands or frequency ratios.

I wouldn't worry that *octave* is too domain-specific, as you are already using *decade* in a domain-specific way.  (In lay English, it refers to a period of 10 years.)

If you really want to avoid the association with frequencies, then it's reasonable to go with *binary decade*, in parallel formation with *binary digit*.  This is generalizable to other bases than just 10 and 2.  For example, while we do have the term *bit* for binary digit, there is no commonly used single-word term for hexadecimal digit.

Comment: [_Binary decade_](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_2.html) would seem to be the accepted term.

Comment: @Gnawme In that source, "binary decade counter" is only a decade counter (counts by ten) which happens to be implemented in binary logic.

Comment: I'd like "binary decade" to be a real term, but Googling it only turns up references like Gnawme's, referring to decimal arithmetic implemented in binary technology. I'll accept this answer given a reference mentioning logarithms as opposed to logic circuits.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The references I quoted (for *decade* and *octave*) specifically mention frequency ratios (which are inherently suited to be represented graphically on a logarithmic scale) and have nothing to do with logic circuits. As of this writing, there aren't any readily available references for *binary decade* the way you want it to be used, because it's simply not (yet) an established term. I only suggested it (as a neologism) because it would work, if you really can't bear to use *octave*. But you mention engineering school. Engineers definitely use *octave*.

Comment: @JohnY Yep, it's possible that's all that was "ringing a bell," no pun intended :) . I'll select this answer, I just invented my own specific terminology for my application. It's a numeric software library, with no relation to frequency or electronics.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. If there is a word or phrase for this, it's not immediately obvious to me. There does seem a use for such a word.

The closest I can come up with would be *order of magnitude*, but that is probably more commonly meant to express different powers of ten. One could be more specific I suppose, saying *binary order of magnitude*.

It seems related to *frequency band*. You'd want a word that can transfer to other bases, so that you don't need to think about ternades, etc. I wonder what the people on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) and [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) could contribute to this? For example, what would you call the range between powers of e in natural logarithms?

*Binary decade* would be understandable, and transferable to other bases, even though it is etymologically impure.

Answer (score 0):

Base two is funny because adding another digit is the same as increasing the **power** of two that's referred to. *Within a power of two of 2^12* or *between 2^5 and 2^6* (where ^ is "to the") cover decade like ranges.

Comment: So the answer here is "power"? Given a context where many similar words are being used canonically, coining such a new definition, however closely related to existing usage, would be very confusing.

Comment: How does this make base-2 "funny"?  Adding another digit in any base is the same as increasing the power (exponent) in that base.  "10^5 to 10^6" is a decade.  The phrase "within a power of 10 of 10^12" means "within a decade of 10^12".